# MathJax add multiple packages

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I want to add multiple packages to MathJax.
i used the line.

```
packages: {'[+]': ['img'],'[+]': ['physics']}
```

but this don't works. image is not rendered in output box.
showing the same thing \img[][200px][200px]{http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/math/courses/MTH015/JPG/Hyperboloids.jpg}.
if i include $\require{img}$ it works.
also if package is like
`packages: {'[+]': ['img']}` no special `\require` is not needed.
How can i fix this.
i am using (https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-img/) for image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
packages: {'[+]': ['img', 'physics']}
```

That's why the value of the key `[+]` in this object is an array.